# The second time I use "getResponse()" in an HttpPost, it works only debugging step by step

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, http-post

I'm using C# on VS2010, FrameWork 4.0.
I wrote a Console Application that makes two Http-Post calls in sequence. 
The second call uses in input what is returned by the first.
Well, when I run the Application in debug mode, step-by-step (F10) using breakpoints, all works fine.
But if I remove the breakpoints and press "F5", I get an exception when my code executes "webRequest.getResponse()" in the SECOND Http-Post call, probably because of a timeout, because the error takes about 60 seconds to appear.

The exception is: ErrorCode 10054 - Connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

This is the class used by my Application (the console application calls the method "Search"):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private string SearchId { get; set; }
        private string XmlOutputSearch { get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        {
            SearchId = "";
            XmlOutputSearch = "";
        }

        public string Search()
        {
            StartSearch();
            CheckResults();
            return XmlOutputSearch;
        }

        public void StartSearch()
        {
            string sInput = "[myStartSearchXmlRequest]";
            string sOutput = HttpPost(sInput);

            XmlDocument myXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            myXmlDoc.LoadXml(sOutput);
            SearchId = myXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SearchId").InnerXml;
        }

        public void CheckResults()
        {
            string sInput = "[myCheckResultsXmlRequest using SearchId]";
            XmlOutputSearch = HttpPost(sInput);
        }

        private string HttpPost(string parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("[myURI]");

                webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
                webRequest.Method = "POST";

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
                Stream os = null;
                try
                { // send the Post
                    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   //Count bytes to send
                    os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         //Send it
                }

                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (os != null)
                    {
                        os.Close();
                    }
                }

                try
                { // get the response

                    // Here I get the exception, on webRequest.GetResponse(), when HttpPost is called 
                    // by CheckResults, if not in Step-By-Step mode
                    using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()) 
                    {
                        if (webResponse == null)
                        { return null; }
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                        string sReturn = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                        sr.Close();
                        webResponse.Close();
                        webRequest.Abort();

                        return sReturn;
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException wex)
                {
                    // This exception will be raised if the server didn't return 200 - OK  
                    // Try to retrieve more information about the network error  
                    if (wex.Response != null)
                    {
                        using (HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(
                                "The server returned '{0}' with the status code {1} ({2:d}).",
                                errorResponse.StatusDescription, errorResponse.StatusCode,
                                errorResponse.StatusCode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in WebResponse. " + excep.Message + " - " + excep.StackTrace);
            }
            return null;
        } // end HttpPost 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to be calling `webRequest.Abort();`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see if there are any errors in the eventlog? Try enabling [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service to know the exact reason. The above error occurs has the following description :

Connection reset by peer.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I used the tracing, but I did not get any extra information.

To avoid the WSAECONNRESET I also tried this: I set "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort = 50000 (decimal)", but did not solve anything.

Some other ideas?

Comment: I tried using WireShark to sniff HTTP POST calls from my PC and found that the second HTTP call (CheckResults) can not even start. I'm sure that my WebRequest is initialized correctly every time, but I still get error.

Comment: Can you put a small time delay between 1st and 2nd call. Ex: Thread.Sleep(3000); delay of 3 seconds.

Comment: I finally found what the problem was: Avast antivirus!

It was blocking my second http post!!

I uninstalled it and now all works fine!

Comment: Nice.. antivirus at times cause problem with development. It would be great if you can find out why the second request was being blocked whereas the first went through.